# String cannot be converted to int error while retrieving JSON data

Tags: java, android, json, okhttp

This is the JSON response which will be received from OkHTTP. This is just one part of the response from the 10 parts of the response.

```
[{"id":418,"title":{"rendered":"testttt"},"content":{"rendered":"
\n\nThis is a random post trying to implement some feature soon and we 
don\u2019t have any option rather than try in the production environment only. 
Just because this is a stupid decision don\u2019t blame me for this, 
please.\n\n<\/p>\n","protected":false}]
```

This is the code I am trying to get the title > rendered is given below :

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://url.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts")
            .build();

    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    String myResponse = response.body().string();
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myResponse);
    for(int i=0; i <=9 ; i++){
        JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("title");
        String title = jsonArray.getString("rendered");
        titles.add(title);
    }
```

But I am getting this `error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int`.

I don't know where I am wrong.

Comment: Would you paste the full logcat error? It seems like your are trying to convert `String` to `int` which should be checked in the logs.

Comment: Error coming when I am trying to build and install the app. So, No logs are generated.

Comment: Android studio pointing this error to this line `String title = jsonArray.getString("rendered");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just checked the `Json` output. It seems like **`title` is not an `Array`** which you are getting-declaring it as an `Array`:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = json.getJSONArray("title");
```

**Try this instead:**

```
for(int i=1; i <= json.length(); i++){
        String title = json.getJSONObject(i).getString("rendered");
        titles.add(title);
    }
```

---

However by converting the same `Json` output to `GSON POJO`, you'll be able to get the data easier and faster than the old ways.

Use: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

And : [Retrieve data using Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20103470/retrieve-data-using-gson)

Comment: Now I am Getting `Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0` error at line 233 which is `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            mList.add(new SlideBean(bgs[i],titlelist[i],icons[i],says[i]));
        }` . titlelist[i] is the problem. I have receiving exactly 10 results through okhttp and adding to title list with this code : `String[] titlelist = (String[]) titles.toArray(new String[titles.size()]);` . Is that Correct???

Comment: You have set the i between `0 - 10` which means 11 items that's why you get the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` error. Updated the answer. `Is that Correct???` It's not, I'm afraid.

Comment: But I have set `i < 10` which means when `i` value equals to 10 it breaks. So, possible values are (0-9) that means 10. If i put `i <=10` that equals to 11.

Comment: How to convert Array list `titles.add(title)` to `String[] titlelist`.

Comment: problem is sorted out. The issue is `titles` is not accessible outside of `async` function. It's my fault to not recognize this.

Comment: You don't need to convert it since it's adding the items into the adapter in order to show it. Oh, glad to hear help.

Answer (score -1):

`titles` list type, if `int` is `string`.

If list type string;

```
jsonArray.get(i).getString("rendered");
```

Example:

```
JSONArray array;
for(int n = 0; n < array.length(); n++)
{
    JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(n);
    // do some stuff....
}
```